# Mockito unit test for Put request is getting an error: java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.name"

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

The problem is with the PUT method unit test when testing the endpoints declared in my UserController and I don't understand what the issue is.

When running a test: testUpdateUser()
then i will get the error: java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.name"
Expected: is "Bob"
but: was "Alice"

My unit test what is getting an error:

```
 @Test
    public void testUpdateUser() throws Exception {
        User user = new User(1, "Alice", "alice", "alice@example.com");
        when(UserDao.getUserById(1)).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(user)); // Retrieve the user from the mock database
        User updatedUser = new User(1, "Bob", "bob", "bob@example.com");

        when(UserDao.updateUser(updatedUser, 1)).thenReturn(1);
        ; // Update the user in the mock database

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(updatedUser);

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = put("/users/1")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Bob")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username", is("bob")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is("bob@example.com")));

        verify(UserDao).updateUser(updatedUser, 1);
        verify(template).convertAndSend("/topic/update", updatedUser);
    }
```

Full error:

```
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /users/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"64"]
             Body = {"id":1,"name":"Bob","username":"bob","email":"bob@example.com"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.padar.controller.UserController
           Method = com.example.padar.controller.UserController#editUsers(int, User, HttpServletRequest)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"70"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"id":1,"name":"Alice","username":"alice","email":"alice@example.com"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.name"
Expected: is "Bob"
     but: was "Alice"
<Click to see difference>


    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$0(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at com.example.padar.controller.UserControllerTest.testUpdateUser(UserControllerTest.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

UserController:

```
@PutMapping("/users/{id}")
 
    public ResponseEntity<?> editUsers(@PathVariable int id,@RequestBody User user, @Autowired HttpServletRequest request){

        LOG.info(
                "FINISHED PROCESSING : METHOD={}; REQUESTURL={}; ID={}; REQUESTBODY={}; OLDUSER={};",
                request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), request.getSession().getId(),
                user.toString(), UserDao.getUserById(id).get(0).toString());
            UserDao.updateUser(user, id);
            template.convertAndSend("/topic/update", UserDao.getUserById(id));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(UserDao.getUserById(id).get(0));


    }
```

UserDao:

```
public class UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final String SQL_GET_ALL_USERS = "SELECT * FROM user";

    private static final String SQL_GET_USER_BY_ID = "SELECT id,name,username,email FROM user where id = ?";

    private static final String SQL_GET_POSTED_USER = "SELECT id,username,email FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_USER_BY_ID = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id=?";

    private static final String SQL_MAKE_NEW_USER = "INSERT INTO user(name,username,email) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    private static final String SQL_UPDATE_USER = "UPDATE user SET name = ?, username = ?, email = ? WHERE id=?";
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_GET_ALL_USERS, new UserMapper());
    }

    public int deleteUserById(int id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_DELETE_USER_BY_ID, id);
    }

    public List<User> getUserById(int id) {return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_GET_USER_BY_ID,new UserMapper(),id); }
    public List<User> showPostedUser() {return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_GET_POSTED_USER,new UserMapper()); }

    public int addUser(User user) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_MAKE_NEW_USER,
                user.getName(),
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getEmail());
        return 1;
    }


    public int updateUser(User user, int id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_UPDATE_USER,
                user.getName(),
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getEmail(),
                id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning `user`, which has the name "Alice". What do you expect to happen? Why are you surprised that it's not the name "Bob"?

Comment: But how do i fix that?

Comment: By setting your mock up in such a way that it returns the correct object? Call me ignorant, but you have two different users (`user` and `updatedUser`) and your code is written to return `user` and then checks for the properties of `updatedUser`. Either change the check, or return the other object. But then: _what are_ you actually testing if everything is mocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are returning the `user`, its name is *Alice*. You can't get *Bob* as an output if Bob is actually not being used to display, right?

Your code is written to return `user` and then checks for the properties of `updatedUser`.

Set your Mockito such that it returns the correct object.